# How to to prevent doctrine2 from returning certain fields

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

What I have coded is a oneToMany relationship with doctrine

one user ---> has many notifications

This is how I get the data

```
/**
 * @Route("/test")
 */
public function testRoute()
{
    //get the user notifications 
    $notifications = $this->getUser()->getNotifications();

    //return json response
    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
    $json = $serializer->serialize($notifications, 'json');
    $response =  new Response($json);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

This is what the controller returns

```
    [
{
    "id": 1,
    "receiver": 1,
    "notification_type": "new_comment",
    "triggered_by": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "gabriel",
      "username_canonical": "gabriel",
      "password":    "3e6bS2I==",
      "email": "ga@ga.de",
      "first_name": "Gabriel",
      "last_name": "ThaKid",
      "likes_counter": 0,
      "dislikes_counter": 2,
      "favourites_counter": 0,
      "profile_pic": "profilepic_60181.png", 
      "salt": "Lqch0N84UH1QmFI5O",
      "form_token": "sO6NgWd",
      "is_active": true, 
      "registration_confirmation": "success",
      "secret_confirmation_id": "qTwNGm4CSKHzJOe8ry9DcXavt",
      "socket_token": "KuMlxYHa"
},
"created_at": "2014-12-16T13:36:20+0100",
"link_to": "#test"
},
{
"id": 2,
"receiver": 1,
"notification_type": "new_comment",
 "triggered_by": {
   "id": 1,
   "username": "gabriel",
   "username_canonical": "gabriel",
   "password": "3e6bS2IYX1DONLA/70a8hzMUQ==",
   "email": "ga@ga.de",
   "first_name": "Gabriel",
   "last_name": "ThaKid",
   "likes_counter": 0,
   "dislikes_counter": 2,
   "favourites_counter": 0,
   "profile_pic": "profilepic_60181.png",
   "profile_rank": "Beginner", (...)
},
   "created_at": "2014-12-16T13:36:24+0100",
   "link_to": "#test"
}
]
```

I think you get the point, it returns the notifications of a certain user which is allright, 
I also need certain fields from the user, like the lastname and the firstname, so the returned data is usable in the application.
But doctrine also returns the hashed password and the salt along with tokens and information the user doesn't need to know.

how do I tell doctrine not to return those fields or not to fetch them to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not about Doctrine, this is the default `Serializer` that tries to fetch and return all of the values available.

Take a look at the [Serializer component documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes-when-serializing) to understand how to ignore properties. Basically, you'll have to pass a normalizer into your serializer's constructor:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;

$normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();
$normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('age'));
$encoder = new JsonEncoder();

$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
$serializer->serialize($person, 'json');
```

Also, I'd strongly suggest to switch to [JMSSerializer](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) and/or use [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), as it gives a lot more flexibility for the serialization. The property list is configured against contexts, and has base exclusion strategies. This way, you'd only need to list properties to expose, not to exclude:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Car:
  exclusion_policy: all
  properties:
    id:
      expose: true
    vendor:
      expose: true
    title:
      expose: true
```

In the given example, all properties that were not listed would be excluded.

Comment: The first code returned an endless loop for some reason, but the JMS bundle solved it for me thanks

Comment: @user3531149, I didn't really mess with the base Serializer myself, that was just a wild guess by the documentation.

Comment: The **setIgnoredAttributes()** method was deprecated since Symfony 4.2 ... [to learn more](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes)

Answer (score 3):

You should create a [custom repository class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).

In this class create a method like this:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/NotificationRepository.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class NotificationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllByUser()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT [only the fields you need] FROM [....]'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

For the DQL query you could use the [partial object syntax](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax).

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you, for any reason, want to use Doctrine's `Paginator`, you have to use `PARTIAL` syntax rather than separate fields.